# Python - read 10min from log file

Tags: python, logging

I need some tool to read latest 10 minutes entry in my log file, and if some words are logged then print some text.

log file:

```
23.07.2014  09:22:11   INFO Logging.LogEvent   0  Failed login test@test.com
23.07.2014  09:29:02   INFO Logging.LogEvent   0  login test@test.com
23.07.2014  09:31:55   INFO Logging.LogEvent   0  login test@test.com
23.07.2014  09:44:14   INFO Logging.LogEvent   0  Failed login test@test.com
```

if during last 10min some entry = Failed -print ALARM.

All what i did is find 'Failed' match but i have no idea how to check last 10min in my log file ;/ -any idea??

```
from sys import argv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

with open('log_test.log', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            e = line.index("Failed")
        except:
            pass
        else:
            print(line)
```

Comment: From your comments on my answer I see that file is sorted and often updated. Is this file just for one day? If it is for one day you can use this fact to ignore date and use only time in comparison. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your format `%d.%m.%Y` is worse than `%Y:%m:%d` which can be used in string comparison.

We also do not know if log is big and if it is sorted. If it is not sorted (it is common for multithreaded applications) you will have to analyze each line and convert it into datetime:

```
def get_dt_from_line(s):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s[:20], '%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S')
```

Then use it as filter (for small files):

```
    MAX_CHECK_TIMEDELTA = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    LOG_START_ANALYZE_DATETIME = (datetime.datetime.today() - MAX_CHECK_TIMEDELTA)
    lines = [s for s in TXT.split('\n') if 'Failed' in s and get_dt_from_line(s) >= LOG_START_ANALYZE_DATETIME]
    print('\n'.join(lines))
```

For big files you can read file line by line.

If your log file is just for one day you can use string comparison instead of datetime comparison:

```
LOG_START_ANALYZE_DATETIME = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)).strftime('%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S')
lines = [s for s in TXT.split('\n') if 'Failed' in s and s >= LOG_START_ANALYZE_DATETIME]
```

Comment: data in log file is sorted and last entry is in the end of file. The problem is that whole log received lot of information every second. Thats why I'm wondering hot to read from the end of file and only 10minutes ;/ ann i need to read data from last 10min end if there is more Failed informations then 10 write some alert to another file which is monitored

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I would lookup line by line, get the timestamp of the first line and then iterate until the difference between the first date and the current one is more than 10 minutes, while counting occurences of the word "Failed".

I think that you'll sort something out with splitting your line following spaces. But be careful as if someday, your log format changes, your script is likely not gonna be working too.